# Why my a frame webvr cant work properly on safari?

Tags: aframe

Anyone know please help, I have worked with that project and every browser work fine except safari

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: This is a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not supported ([source1](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webvr), [source2](https://webvr.rocks/#browsers))